# Add functionality to a submit button php

Tags: php, button, submit, action

I have several divs which containing images. I want to add below or beside those divs a submit checkbox with two values and perform an action when the user press the submit button. My php code is the following:

```
echo '<div>';
echo '<img src="'. ($image) .'"  alt=""/>';
echo '</div>';

echo'<LABEL FOR="C1">Fashion</LABEL>';
echo'<INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name="fashion" ID="C1" Value="Fashion">';

echo'<LABEL FOR="C2"> Non Fashion </LABEL>';
echo'<INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name="nfashion" ID="C2" Value="Non Fashion">';
echo'<input type="submit" value="submit" action = "action.php">';
```

What is the functionality I should add in action.php? Is the correct way to add functionality yo submit button? In the action.php I want to write add in a text file the name of the image and the choice between fashion and nfashion. How can I perform the submit without leaving the main page I am already in, that with image div? Instead of using action.php can I use a php function which will be defined in the same php file?

Comment: the `<form>` tag should have the `action` attribute, not the `input` submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see this tutorial:
[php_forms](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

```
echo '<form action="action.php" method="post">';
echo '<div>';
echo '<img src="'. ($image) .'"  alt=""/>';
echo '</div>';

echo'<LABEL FOR="C1">Fashion</LABEL>';
echo'<INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name="fashion" ID="C1" Value="Fashion">';

echo'<LABEL FOR="C2"> Non Fashion </LABEL>';
echo'<INPUT TYPE="Checkbox" Name="nfashion" ID="C2" Value="Non Fashion">';
echo'<input type="submit" value="submit" action = "action.php">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Thus I had to check $_POST['fashion'] and $_POST['nfashion']?

Answer (score 1):

The form is submitted, so the `action` attribute belongs to the from.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

The button just triggers the submission of the form (`type="submit"`). There are other ways to submit a form, for example hitting `enter` key in a Textfield (if there is a submit button), or via javascript (`document.formName.submit()`).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can just
   http://pastebin.com/bg2Pv7CY

//Sry for not pasting code here, for unknown reason it was oputing onlyu labels values here.

2.What do you mean by functionality?

Comment: I want to write to a txt file if a user choose fashion or not fashion.

Comment: Than in action.php you will need to use $_POST['text-field-name'] as a variable holding what user wrote in the form.

You can also (maybe even should) use isset() to check if the variable was set during form interaction

Comment: Is there a way for the user not to be able to choose both two options in checkbox?

Comment: Maybe replace them with radio buttons? You can also wrote short js script to keep only one checked